Kubernetes priorityClass setting is ignored
I had the following pending pods in my single-node k8s cluster (on-premise, built with kubeadm, version:1.30.3):
Pod1, priority=330954640
Pod2, priority=330954559
Pod3, priority=330954525

These pods were created using the same manifest template, and have the same settings (e.g. images, cpu/memory requests, etc.) other than the name and the priorityClass. The preemptionPolicy is set to Never for all pods.
When there were enough resources to run only one Pod, the Pod2 entered the Running state and the other Pods remained in the Pending state. I expected the Pod1 to enter the Running state as it has the highest priority, but this was not the case.
I searched around to find out how the k8s manages the Pending pods but could not find any reason why the priority was ignored in my case... does anyone have any ideas?
UPDATE:
I have found that this problem occurs in situations where the pods are transitive to Running immediately after creation, but not in other situations (e.g. 10 minutes after creation).

As you have enough resources to run only one pod, the reason for the pending state is Insufficient resources if the resource is not available at exact time while pod1 was created, but it became available a short period of time when pod2 was created. So pod2 might get scheduled first.
Reviewing logs can help to provide details about why pod2 was scheduled instead of pod1. By using below command : Kubectl logs -n kube-system -l component=kube-scheduler,  it will fetch logs from all pods in the ‘kube-system’ namespace that have the label ‘component=kube-scheduler’.
Non-preempting pods may still be preempted by other, high-priority pods. Try kubectl get events, this will show the issue (and all other events) why pod has not been scheduled. As you are saying  preemptionPolicy is set to Never, pods in that PriorityClass will be non-preempting. Refer to this document PreemptionPolicy for mode details.

Do you mean that the priorityClass would be ignored for a moment just after the pod was created? I looked at the kube-scheduler logs, but nothing was logged during scheduling.

Correct,  Where the priority class seems to be ignored due to the timing and order of the events in the Kubernetes scheduler. If the pod's resource requests can be satisfied without preempting other pods, the scheduler might skip a full priority-based evaluation.

Setting preemptionPolicy to Never means a pod won't preempt other pods, even if it has a higher priority. This could lead to scenarios where a lower-priority pod gets scheduled first if resources are limited.

Thanks, do you have any references that shows priorities might be ignored? I am trying to prove that could happen but still not able to find any official articles...

It's difficult to find explicit documents stating that priorities can be completely ignored by the Kubernetes scheduler. Kube scheduler is designed to prioritize based on pod priorities.

If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information
